# #1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, xml

I have this XML:

```
<product>
<id>3</id>
<name>myname</name>
<weight>67</weight>
<price>$34.00</price>
</product>
```

I also have a mysql table:

```
+-----------+--------+-------------+
| ID        | Title  | Price       |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
|         1 | title1 | $19.00      |
|         2 | title2 | $24.00      |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to insert the xml file into the table with this code:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'pathtothefile/filename.xml'
INTO TABLE mytable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'
SET ID = id, Title=name, Price=price;
```

But I get this error  #1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'pathtothefile/filename.xml'
INTO TABLE mytable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'
SET ID = id, Title=`name`, Price=price;
;
```

Or this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'pathtothefile/filename.xml'
INTO TABLE mytable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'
(ID, Title, Price)
;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Now I'll do it in another way, but I'd like to understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to write a single SQL statement that will do the XML to database field mapping, if the names of the corresponding fields are not identical.

Create a temporary table that has column names identical to the XML tags, or create a temp like mytable and ALTER. Then these statements will be sufficient :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE myXMLtable LIKE mytable;

ALTER myXMLtable... (rename the fields like you have them in the XML)

LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/whatever/filename.xml'
INTO TABLE myXMLtable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>';
```

Afterwards rename again and copy the myXMLtable entries to mytable.